# App Privacy Policy Error at mainactivity.java

Tags: android, android-activity

```
public void requestConsent() {
    URL privacyUrl = null;
    try {
        // TODO: Replace with your app's privacy policy URL.
        privacyUrl = new URL("https://davutotel.com/privacy");
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        // Handle error.
    }
```

Although I give the Privacy Policy link here, I get the same error again where I am doing it wrong.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You should also understand [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: where do you get this error? compiling? runtime? please edit the question and post the exact text of the message or provide a screenshot. It isn't clear what your problem is.